# Correlation between Connection Per User and Response Time

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, performance-testing

I am using Visual Studio to test an end point that is built on C# and ASP.Net Core. I found there's a huge correlation between connection per user and response time.

Here's an example. I didn't change any other configuration but connections per user:

Connections per user: 1000

[image]

Connections per user: 20

[image]

Could someone explain what is connection per user? And how come it doesn't impact the user load number and request per second much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this article here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/load-test-run-settings-properties?view=vs-2019

Effectively you are just increasing the concurrent calls. A browser would make more calls simultaneously thus increasing the concurrent load. I would expect that after a value it would make no difference depending on the implementation.

You must be having great wait times with so many connections in your api.

- The Connection Per User model simulates the behavior of a user who is using a real browser. When Internet Explorer 6 or Internet Explorer 7 is simulated, each virtual user who is running a web performance test uses one or two dedicated connections to the web server. The first connection is established when the first request in the web performance test is issued. A second connection may be used when a page contains more than one dependent request. These requests are issued in parallel by using the two connections. These connections are reused for subsequent requests in the web performance test. The connections are closed when the web performance test finishes. A drawback to this model is that the number of connections that is held open on the agent computer might be high (up to two times the user load). Consequently, the resources that are required to support this high connection count might limit the user load that can be driven from a single load test agent. When Internet Explorer 8 is simulated, six concurrent connections are supported.
- The Connection Pool model conserves the resources on the load test agent by sharing connections to the web server among multiple virtual web performance test users. If the user load is larger than the connection pool size, the web performance tests that are run by different virtual users will share a connection. This could mean that one web performance test might have to wait before it issues a request when another web performance test is using the connection. The average time that a web performance test waits before it submits a request is tracked by the load test performance counter Average Connection Wait Time. This number should be less than the average response time for a page. If it is not, the connection pool size is probably too small.

Answer (score 0):

**The Connection Per User** - Each virtual user of a web test uses a dedicated connection to the web server, and that connection is closed when the web test session completes.

To reduce the connection per user please apply below logic -

1. Add more think time between transactions it will reduce the request per second and connections.
2. Add pacing/delay between the transactions
3. slow ramp up for the load test